# Only accepting values > 100000 into an array, those below 100000 will count as 1

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner to Java and trying to code a program that will take in the number of views for each episode of a netflix series and eventually give me back the average number of views. However, I have been told to only count view numbers above 50000, anything below will count as 1 view. How would I implement this?

```
public class assignmentnetflix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       int[] NetflixShow;
       NetlixShow = new int[10];   
             
      for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
        System.out.println("Enter the number of views of Season 4 Episode " + (i+1));
        NetflixShow[i] = input.nextInt();
      }

      input.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: `Javascript !== Java`

Comment: "How would I implement this?"  With a second `for` loop coded after the first `for` loop to calculate the sum of viewings.  After the second `for` loop is finished, calculate the average.

Comment: With an `if`-`else` statement somehow. For example, if the number of views is 100 000 or less, add 1 to the running total, otherwise add the number of views.

Comment: Start simple. Can you write the code to calculate a (normal) average? After you have done that, we can more easily discuss how to modify it to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The more correct way is to use the if statement. If it is greater than or equal to 50000 or 100000, add the original number, and if it is less than 50000, add 1. Learn to loop through statements and conditional judgment statements.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] NetflixShow= new int[10];

        for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of views of Season 4 Episode " + (i+1));
            NetflixShow[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(function(NetflixShow,10));
        input.close();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param NetflixShow array
     * @param len the length of array
     * @return average
     */
    static long  function(int [] NetflixShow,int len)
    {
        long sum=0;
        for(int num:NetflixShow)
        {
            if(num>=100000) sum+=num;
            else sum+=1;
        }
        return sum/len;
    }
```

Comment: the code is above